# Module parse failed: Unexpected token error with @prismicio/react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, prismic.io

I have a react app created with CRA using prismic.io. It used to work but now I keep getting module not found error which I keep fixing by running `npm install @prismicio/react @prismicio/client @prismicio/helpers` after which I get the following error:

```
./node_modules/@prismicio/react/dist/PrismicRichText.js 115:23
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (115:23)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       var img = /* @__PURE__ */jsx("img", {
|         src: node.url,
>         alt: node.alt ?? void 0,
|         "data-copyright": node.copyright ? node.copyright : void 0
|       });
```

Anyone have any idea what to do?

I have tried rm node modules and package-lock and reinstalling everything multiple times with no success.